# bootstrap modal content is not responsive

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap modal in my application but when i see in mobile it's content is shows out of modal. I tried to use min width of modal so if modal show in mobile screen that width should not go beyond from min width.
but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `max-width` it will restrict the div that you are using to go beyond the limit.

I think in this case min-width is what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Thanks it's working fine. I am marking it as answer.

Comment: You are welcome. and always remember to keep using max-width to maintain responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `div class="container"` (with brackets, I don't know how to type it with them) to the inside of the modal.

Also, it might help if you could show me your code.